# Skip RegEx grouping

Tags: java, regex

I have added a code wih regex ""\(.*?\)" to pattern match words enclosed in ( and ) and replace those values.
Fr eg: test_value_(obj_id)_(date_created) will be replaced by values of obj_id and date_created. final string would be "test_value_123_10/23/19"  ( obj_id value being 123 and date_created 10/23/19)

But if there is any expression where the user needs ( and ) to be part of value along with final string. for eg: test_value_((obj_id))_(date_created). 
Regex pattern doesnt work and it doesnt recognise the group obj_id. so final expression returned as "test_value_((obj_id))_10/23/19"
Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Can you please clarify more you question?

Comment: Could you show the code of what you already have? I'm not sure why you're using `"\(.*?\)"` when you could just use `"test_value_(obj_id)_(date_created)".replace("obj_id","(123)").replace("date_created("10/23/19");`. I'm assuming you do something generic so it works for all variables (using reflection even maybe?), and you therefore use `\(.*?\)` to get all values within parentheses (one by one, which is why you're having an issue now when the value contains parentheses), and replace them with the value of this variable.

Comment: okay the reason I cant use replace is that it will be more generic and the expression is set by the user. To make it more clear for you guys, this list of values are supplied by the user and also the expression which is used to construct value is also set by the user so they can change it anytime they want. User submits the values through a form submission and these data is processed in a method.  So I have provided a configuration where they can define

Answer (score 2):

Change the regex to

```
\([^()]*\)
```

which will match innermost parenthesed expressions only. If the strings your users supplies would contain parenthese pairs not containing expressions to substitute, you either have to be more strict about the pattern describing data to substitute or change the delimiting chars you use.

You might want to start with

```
\([a-zA-Z_]+\)
```

as your pattern which matches parenthesed identifiers without digits.

Comment: \([^()]*?\) this actually works for me. Thanks for the help.  I define the rules to set expression, just that this one scenario where the attribute value should be enclosed with ( , ) was failing.

Comment: For very slightly improved performances, I suggest removing the `?` from `*?` since now the character class can't match more than it should. With the lazy quantified token the regex engine checks if it can match the rest of the regex each time the quantified token matches a character, while the greedy quantified token will match as much as it can, then backtrack until the rest of the regex can match

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you want:

```
    String string1 = "test_value_(obj_id)_(date_created)";
    String string2 = "test_value_((obj_id))_(date_created)";

    String objectId = "123";
    String dateCreated = "10/23/19";

    String result1 = string1.replaceAll("(?<!\\()\\(obj_id\\)(?!\\))", objectId)
            .replaceAll("(?<!\\()\\(date_created\\)(?!\\))", dateCreated);

    String result2 = string2.replaceAll("(?<!\\()\\(obj_id\\)(?!\\))", objectId)
            .replaceAll("(?<!\\()\\(date_created\\)(?!\\))", dateCreated);

    System.out.println(string1 + " --> " + result1);
    System.out.println(string2 + " --> " + result2);

    // prints:
    // test_value_(obj_id)_(date_created) --> test_value_123_10/23/19
    // test_value_((obj_id))_(date_created) --> test_value_((obj_id))_10/23/19
```